# nftables doesn't work even though config file exists

Tags: nftables

I'm using nftables on Debian 10.
There is my config file

```
# cat /etc/nftables.conf
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0;
        }
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority 0;
        }
        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority 0;
        }
}
```

And the service file

```
[Unit]
Description=nftables
Documentation=man:nft(8) http://wiki.nftables.org
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target shutdown.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
StandardInput=null
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nft -f /etc/nftables.conf
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nft -f /etc/nftables.conf
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/nft flush ruleset

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

But nftables doesn't work correctly. There are some examples:

`nft list tables` : no output

...

```
# nft list table inet filter
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
list table inet filter
                ^^^^^^
```

....

```
# nft add table ip filter
Error: Could not process rule: Operation not supported
add table ip filter
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why? And How to fix it?

Comment: Are you able to load the ruleset using `nft -f /etc/nftables.conf`?

Comment: @larsks Oh. It worked. I ran `nft flush ruleset;nft -f /etc/nftables.conf` to load the ruleset. But I wonder why it has to be loaded manually? I thought it run automatically?

Answer (score 3):

The `nftables` package for your distribution probably provides a mechanism that will automatically load your nftables rules for you when the system boots. On Fedora, for example, you can enable the `nftables` service...

```
systemctl enable nftables
```

...which will load the configuration from `/etc/sysconfig/nftables.conf`.

If you can tell us what distribution you're using, we can probably help figure out the appropriate mechanism.

Comment: Sorry. I added the distribution. I'm using Debian 10.

Comment: You show a unit file in your question. Is it enabled (`systemctl enable nftables`)? Does it work when you start the service (`systemctl start nftables`)? Are there errors in your journal when you try to start the service?

Comment: It hasn't work already. It can list ruleset in `/etc/nftables.conf` by `nft list ruleset` but when I add a rule, it still gets error.


`# nft add rule inet filter input tcp dport ssh ip saddr xxx reject`
`Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory`
`add rule inet filter input tcp dport ssh ip saddr xxx reject`
`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`

Comment: I have the same problem under Armbian buster. Starting the service helps but I can only run `nft list ruleset`, `nft flush ruleset` and `nft -f /etc/nftables.conf`, the rest produces: "Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory", i.e "nft insert rule ip filter INPUT tcp dport 80 counter accept". @larsks Your help is warmly welcome.